# Links in style.css will not update

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have a website, I moved the site to a new pc, loaded it up into dreamweaver, however the links for images in the css are still pointing to the old location, I have tried to change them but them will always revert back tot he old location. I tried uploading the site then downloading the style.css to see if that could kick it, but i will not.

When I open up the style.css I can see the old location, (yes I have always used the properties to add the location of header images.

As a last resort I manually changed the style.css, however I will not work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the link for the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your paths are absolute instead of relative. Absolute path won't work if you relocate your image or HTML files into different folders or change your folder structure. The browser won't be able to find the image file.